# Error adding geofences in Android (status code 1000)

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services, android-location, android-geofence

I am getting an error in the `onAddGeofencesResult(int statusCode, String[] geofenceRequestIds)` callback with `statusCode = 1000`.

I have my GPS enabled and my WiFi. I also have Google Play Services and I am able to track my location and request updates. Why am I not able to add geofences? I am not able to add geofences even from the documentation sample app. I get the following Toast message:

> "Add Geofences: Failure, error code 1000 GeofenceRequestIds=[1,2,1,2]"

From the documentation (statusCode 1000):

`public static final int GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE`

> Geofence service is not available now. Typically this is because the user turned off location access in settings > location access.
>
> Constant Value: 1000 (0x000003e8)

Answer (score 43):

You get `GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE` (code '1000') when user disagrees to "Use Google' location services" in Settings->Location->Mode: [image]

To fix it:

- go to Settings->Location->Mode
  [image]
- set "Device only (Use GPS to determine your location)"
- set any other option to get the popup (e.g. "High accuracy (Use GPS, Wi-Fi and mobile networks to determine location")
- dialog ""Use Google' location services" is shown
- choose "Agree"

Comment: thats not very helpful comment, what does not work, hat device, what os?

Comment: I'm getting `Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 1000, resolution=null}` after `GeofencingClient.addGeofences()` and the emulator has Mode set to `Device only`. Emulator image is using Android 7.1.1 with Google API's

Comment: UPDATE: I just now set the `Settings` -> `Location` -> `Mode` to `High Accuracy` and I was able to set the geofence successfully !  (I hate working with GPS on Android!)

Comment: I've found that on a **real device**, using `Device only` works just fine to set a geofence. (as does `Battery Saving`)

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere I get the same status code `1000` when using `Device only` mode on **Galaxy S6**

Answer (score 15):

Posting this answer since the settings in Android have changed a lot. I had this error twice when I was running a Nexus 5X emulator running API 28. I managed to solve it both times by doing the following:

1. Turn off your application you are developing (don't let it be in the background)
2. Go to Settings -> Security & Location -> Location -> Advanced -> Google Location Accuracy. Turn 'Improve Location Accuracy' **off**.

[image]

3. Turn **on** 'Improve Location Accuracy'

Turn on your application again and adding geofences worked for me after I took these steps.

EDIT: I ran into this issue again a few months later, sometimes the emulator is stubborn and does not actually turn on location accuracy correctly to allow Google's Geofence API to recognise it is turned on. I had turn 'Improve Location Accuracy' on and off at least 10 times before location accuracy worked.

Comment: For an APK 28 emulator toggling this on fixed the error.

Comment: @user836003 asking this for others in the future, did you have to toggle it multiple times before it worked?

Comment: As of today (20th March 2020), question is still receiving upvotes; assuming this answer is still relative.

Comment: As of today, still receiving upvotes; assuming this answer is still relative.

Answer (score 6):

Is a little later, but just now I had this issue. My guess is:

*you are using any kind of fake GPS on your tests (Lockito, emulator, etc)?*

I took some hours until I found out that the fake locations seems to disable the Geofence support! You cannot register or trigger a Geofence if you are not really in the location.

If you turn off the fake GPS,the Geofence support become enabled again.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the statusCode 1000 when i was trying to run this app on the emulator. The thing which fixed this was to go in Settings-> locations and access-> Check the enable wifi and gps option on the emulator and it will fix it

Answer (score 2):

You actually gave the answer in your question:
Geofence service is not available now. Typically this is because the user turned off location access in settings > location access.

I had this same issue, and just going to settings --> location and making sure I select the mode for high accuracy fixed this issue.

PS Device only mode is not good enough, it needs to be High accuracy mode.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your phone must be compatible:
`A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.2 or higher and includes Google Play Store.`

Just to be sure, you need to have Google Play service [installed correctly](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Sometimes, just restarting your phone can fix this problem.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs also when location service is not enabled. You need to set it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I did silly mistake:

Error occurred because **Device does not have Permission for GPS (Location service).**

More details on Geofencing API [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi).

Screen shots for reference:

[image]
[image]

Hope this will make you clear.

Answer (score 0):

For my targetSdkVersion 28 and minSdkVersion 24, this is what worked for me on emulator running Pixel XL API 27:

I selected `High accuracy` in the `Settings -> Location -> Mode`. Originally it was set to `Device only`.

This popped up a message to with `Agree` and `Disagree` options. I selected `Agree`.

After that the error went away.

I tried the other option `Battery Saving`. This also worked fine.

But when reverted back to `Device only`, it started giving this error again.

So in case of emulator `Location mode` should bet set to `High accuracy` or `Battery saving`.

On my actual device, which is a Nexus 6P device, it was already set to `High accuracy` and I haven't checked it for `Device only`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow this official link to make broadcast for geofence.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#java

"make sure that you call your **Geofence.Builder** and **geofencingClient.addGeofences** methods in **onStart** of your mainActivity after you have called **googleApiClient.connect()**."

then finally if you set location mode in settings i.e **GPS or wifi only**. You will get this error.(in case u are using emulator)
Choose **high accuracy** mode and you will be able to add geofences.
Hope this helps. Best Of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 9.0:
I read MinistryOfChaps answer and I tried do this for one hour but it has not worked to me. So I turned off my app, turned off 'Improve Location Accuracy', turned off Scanning > wi-fi scanning and bluetooth scannig, and I turned off my User location too. After this, I turn on all these options and my geofence finally is working

Answer (score 0):

for android oreo to android S make sure to access setting high priority

```
fun ceksetting(){
val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
val locationRequest = LocationRequest()
    locationRequest!!.interval = 50000
    locationRequest!!.fastestInterval = 50000
    locationRequest!!.smallestDisplacement = 170f // 170 m = 0.1 mile
    locationRequest!!.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY //set according to your app function
    val client: SettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(requireActivity())
    val task: Task<LocationSettingsResponse> = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
    task.addOnSuccessListener { locationSettingsResponse ->
       //here call your geofence
    }

    task.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        if (exception is ResolvableApiException){
            // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
            // by showing the user a dialog.
            try {
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                exception.startResolutionForResult(requireActivity(),
                    REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS)
            } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                // Ignore the error.
            }
        }
    }
}
```