# Google geofencing not working, always GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: java, android, google-api, android-geofence

I'm trying so many days using the Google Location API for define geofences in the map, i use the [Smart Location Library](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib) togheter with genymotion and [Lockito](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.dvilleneuve.lockito&hl=es_419) for test my geofences but at the time at i start the lockito test my IntentService catchs the google geofencing event with an error code of 1000 and in the [Google APIs for Android docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofenceStatusCodes.html#GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE) this means a GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE error, i do the tests using genymotion and my Moto G3 but the results are the same, then i try to test proyects from github and the rusults are also the same, i ensure that in my devices the GPS is on and in the best accuracy; i try with the following projects and nothing changes the error:

- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-geofences-on-android--cms-26639
- https://github.com/vhoen/Android-Geofence-21 with this one i'm getting a message that tells me the geofencing service is not running at startup in my genymotion emulator but in my Moto G3 not, but the error anyways appears when i use lockito.

Extra data: tests were done in phones with android 6.0, i do the tests with Google services 9.6.1 and 9.4.0 and the results vary.

Comment: just use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27169357/7163567) You get GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE (code '1000') when user disagrees to "Use Google' location services" in Settings->Location->Mode worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was using Lockito, you must test other apps for simulate locations in genymotion or real devices.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using the Genymotion emulator and had a similar GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE error. The reason, in my particular case, was that Google Play Services was not installed on the emulator.