# Xamarin Forms - Android.Gms.Common.Apis.ApiException: 1000 on Android emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation, android-emulator, geofencing

I have created a xamarin forms application that uses the shiny library for location/notification/geofences. When I build the application and start a geofence on my android emulator on visual studio, it says: Android.Gms.Common.Apis.ApiException: 1000. The error is shown after when I try to create (thus check for geofences) a geofence.

What does this mean and how can I get rid of this? I want the emulator to check for geofences.

Comment: As document said here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofenceStatusCodes#public-static-final-int-geofence_not_available try turn on settings > location access for your emulator

Comment: Do I need to go to settings in the emulator itself? Or settings outside the emulator via the vertical bar next to the emulator?

Comment: Should be the emulator itself

Comment: If I go to settings -> apps & notifications -> app permissions -> Location, it shows that it's permissble on my emulator. Is that what is ment by the docs? Because I can't find settings -> location access on the emulator and neither on the bar next to the emulator..

Comment: Setting descriptions differ from devices, looks like it's what the doc says.

Comment: Allright, thanks,  it still doesn't work.. very weird.

Comment: Found an earlier post about this error, maybe you can try with it's answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082482/error-adding-geofences-in-android-status-code-1000